# Don't quite understand BeginUmbracoForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sA6YAFFk4UQ&index=12&list=PLLYO0Qmbv5pvGjpI6Cyg3mVBoYtG_LK63) tutorial, to create a Contact Us form using Umbraco and Mvc - and I am a bit puzzled as to why a certain thing works. Specifically, - how does ContactForm (a partial view) both displays the content of the Contact Us page (by the calling of @Html.Action("ShowForm", "ContactSurface")), and also handles the submit button (how does it knows to only call HandleFormPost when the submit button is pressed?﻿)

Here's the view / template for holding the Contact Us webpage.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.ContactHolder>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
@Html.Action("ShowForm", "ContactSurface")
```

Here's the Controller:

```
public class ContactSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult ShowForm()
    {
        ContactModel myModel = new ContactModel();
        return PartialView("ContactForm", myModel);
    }

    public ActionResult HandleFormPost(ContactModel model)
    {
        var newComment = Services.ContentService.CreateContent(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + " " + model.Name, CurrentPage.Id, "ContactFormula");
        newComment.SetValue("emailFrom", model.Email);
        newComment.SetValue("contactName", model.Name);
        newComment.SetValue("contactMessage", model.Message);
        Services.ContentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(newComment);
        return RedirectToCurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

And here's a partial view for actually displaying the form, and apparently also create the new ContactFormula (a document type for saving contact us submissions - it has emailFrom, contactName and contactMessage in it).

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ProjectDemo.Models.ContactModel>
@using CohensCigarsDemo.Controllers;
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<ContactSurfaceController>("HandleFormPost"))
{

    <label for="emailFrom">E-mail</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "emailFrom", placeholder = "E-mail" }) 
    <br />
    <label for="nameFrom">Name</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "nameFrom", placeholder = "Name" }) 
    <br />
    <label for="messageFrom">Message</label>
    <br />
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new { @class = "messageFrom", placeholder = "Message" })   

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller has 2 methods, 1 for showing the form `ShowForm` and 1 for the business logic that is executed after the submit button is pressed `HandleFormPost`

All the routing information is in the following statement

```
Html.BeginUmbracoForm<ContactSurfaceController>("HandleFormPost")
```

Html.BeginUmbracoForm is only a wrapper around Razors own `Html.BeginForm` with some additional functionality for routing.

The above statement creates something like

```
<form method="post" action="umbraco/surface/contact/handleformpost">
```

The forms now routes to the HandleFormPost method in the ContactSurfaceController (this is standard [MVC routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)).
And because of the submit button the browser know what to do after it's clicked

`ContactModel` is just a strongly typed object for the fields in your form and with some MVC magic the fields are automatically maped to a `ContactModel` object when the form is submitted and based on this model the new umbraco documenttype is created using `Services.ContentService.CreateContent`

For more explanation on creating a form using MVC, check out [this article](https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/)

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. Can you please add some more explanation on the regular BeginForm. Also - what exactly calls what. Specifically - what does ContactForm (the last snippet) does under ShowForm and under the Submit / Handle Form Post?

Comment: I've added a little bit of extra explanation as well as a link to a tutorial on how to create a form using Razor